# (2/2) ErrorException Object of class stdClass could not be converted to int in laravel 5

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I want to create a tax summary of invoice in which i want to add total according to different tax rate.For example:- 2.5% taxrate has its own products and 6% taxrate has its own product.i want to do this in for loop.I have used following code but it did not work.please tell me what is wrong in this code.it did not show correct total.I have a table name is sales_items. Its field are id,invoice_id,cgst_percentage,cgst_amount,sgst_percentage etc.The image is as

[image]

Controller.php

```
    $data['query1']= DB::table('sales_items')->distinct()->get(['cgst_percentage']);
    // I am using this variable in foreach loop in view file.
```

View.blade.php

```
    <?php $data_total= array();  ?>
    <?php $cgst_unique_data= array(); ?>

 @foreach($query1 as $cgst_data=>$value)


    <?php 

    $cgst_unique_data= DB::table('sales_items')->where('cgst_percentage','=',$value->cgst_percentage)->where('invoice_id','=',$sales_item->invoice_id)->get();

    ?>

     @foreach($cgst_unique_data as $total=>$value) 

     <?php

     $data_total = $total_amount + $total;
     $data_total= $data_total + $value;
     ?> 
     @endforeach

     {{ $data_total }}

 @endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$value` variable is an object that holds a row from your `cgst_unique_data` query results. You can't simply add that to other integer variables like you do in

```
$data_total= $data_total + $value;
```

You'll need to access a specific column from that row that you want to add. If the column name was `someName`, you'd need to do:

```
$data_total= $data_total + $value->someName;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.